# why does the class variable does not have value in struct in swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct

I was just trying what would be the value of class variable inside a struct to if copies of struct are created. Below is the code

```
import Foundation

class Name {
    var name :String

    init(nname : String) {
        self.name = nname
    }
}

struct A {
    var NewName: Name
    var age: Int = 0

    init(nName: Name,nAge : Int){
        self.age = nAge
        self.NewName = nName
    }
}

var myName = Name(nname : "Sia")
var test1 = A(nName: myName,nAge:30)
var test2 = test1
print(test1.NewName)
print(test2.NewName)
```

output

```
__lldb_expr_182.Name
__lldb_expr_182.Name
```

I'm not able to understand why the output is so ? I'm just trying, no specific reason to include class variable inside a struct.

Comment: You should print `test1.NewName.name` and `test2.NewName.name` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Name` is a class the property value stored in the struct (`NewName`) is a reference to that class instance. When you copy the struct to another you copy the reference value (i.e. the address in memory the instance is stored in). Hence the two properties reference the same `Name` instance and show the same print value (although the two structs are of different instances).

**EDIT**: if you meant why it does not print "Sia"

you are printing a reference value, not the property stored in it. (`NewName` is not a string but a reference to a class)

Comment: you are correct and hence I was expecting output "Sia"  but it is different

Answer (score 1):

You are not using class variables at all, you are using instance variables. A *class* variable exists only once for a whole class. An *instance* variable is different for each instance of the class (or instance of the struct). That's just confusing to readers of your question.

The big difference between a Swift class and a Swift struct is that classes are *references*, while structs are *values*. When you assign myName = Name(nname : "Sia"), you create an instance of type Name, and myName is a reference to that instance.

test1 is a newly created struct. It doesn't contain the value of myName, it contains a reference. test2 is also a newly created struct. It doesn't copy the whole Name object from test1, it only copies the reference. test1 and test2 use the same reference.

If you changed myName.name = "abc", then the value inside the object that myName references is changed, so printing test1.NewName.name or test1.NewName.name will print "abc".